# Undefined symbols: _SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, admob

Getting below issue on AdMob Native ads demo

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_SKStoreProductParameterAdNetworkSourceIdentifier", referenced from:
l030 in GoogleMobileAds(GADInAppStoreMonitor.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

- Xcode 14.0
- Mac OS : Monterey 12.6.1
- Chip : M2
- Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK : 10.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 14.0 doesn't support Google Mobile Ads SDK version > 10.3.0 so you need to use 10.3.0.

pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '10.3.0'